# How to isolate foundation of addition from existing house?

Tags: foundation, addition

Our house is quite small, 750sf, built in the 1920s, has a crawlspace and a rather questionable stone masonry foundation.

We are hoping to add another bedroom, 14'x12' with a turndown edge slab, as shown in the included picture.

I have been doing research on how this could be done but everything I have seen shows a physical connection between the existing foundation and the new slab. This is usually accomplished by epoxying rebar into holes drilled in the foundation which extends into the concrete of the new slab.

I am concerned that the foundation wall may not be considered sound enough to support this connection and that substantial work will be required to shore it up. This would almost certainly cost more than we can afford right now.

My question is: Is there a way that an addition can be built in sort of a freestanding way where the foundations do not require a physical connection?

I am also interested in how the above ground parts of such an addition need to be connected to the house. For instance, does the stucco exterior need to be removed where the walls and roof join up or can they be basically bolted to the exterior? But perhaps that can wait for another question.

[image: A simple representation of the addition]

Comment: You need to better describe the existing foundation. It sounds likes you may be applying a surcharge load on the backfill behind a foundation wall that you don't trust.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you did the epoxy connections, then would the existing foundation need to support your slab-on-grad? Or would your slab on grade need to support the existing foundation? Maybe this is an opportunity to reinforce your questionable foundation.

Comment: What's your seismic category? If you don't know, then where are you doing this work? In the IRC's seismic categories A, B, and C your footings don't technically require any rebar. I would find it odd if a building official demanded doweling for continuity between the two structures. In seismic category D your footings have rebar requirements, so I'm not sure whether or not a building official would bother.

Comment: The IRC has a "Rubble stone masonry" section that might represent your foundation. IRC 404.1.8.

Comment: Are you doing the foundation work yourself or are you contracting it out? If contracting it out, this is a question for your foundation contractor. He should be able to explain all the options and make recommendations. Also, if you haven't yet chosen a contractor, please be sure to get estimates from 3 or 4 and ask each of them about this specific issue.